# Why the cmake dependent step doesn't execute on my external boost project?

Tags: visual-c++, boost, cmake

I would like to build boost before configure step only if there are no files generated to prevent unnecessary processing. When I go configure in cmake I can't see anything happens. I'm able to perform a building properly at build step (without checking dependent files), but it doesn't work for me for configure step.

Looking at docs it should work (it seems to me it should do), the cmake configures without any feedback and errors

```
ExternalProject_Add(boost
    DOWNLOAD_COMMAND  ""
    SOURCE_DIR        "${BOOST_ROOT}"
    BUILD_IN_SOURCE   1
    BUILD_ALWAYS      1
    INSTALL_COMMAND   ""
    TEST_COMMAND      ""
)

ExternalProject_Add_Step(boost launchBootstrap
    WORKING_DIRECTORY "${BOOST_ROOT}"
    DEPENDS           "b2.exe"
    COMMENT           "Custom Configure Boost Step - launch bootstrap script"
    COMMAND           bootstrap.bat --prefix=BAWGeneratedBuild --with-toolset=msvc --with-libraries=date_time,filesystem,regex,system,program_options,thread,iostreams,atomic
    USES_TERMINAL     1
)

ExternalProject_Add_Step(boost buildBoost
    WORKING_DIRECTORY "${BOOST_ROOT}"
    DEPENDS           "stage/lib/libboost_atomic-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_74.lib"
                      "stage/lib/libboost_atomic-vc142-mt-x64-1_74.lib"
                      "stage/lib/libboost_chrono-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_74.lib"
                      "stage/lib/libboost_chrono-vc142-mt-x64-1_74.lib"
                      "stage/lib/libboost_date_time-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_74.lib"
                      "stage/lib/libboost_date_time-vc142-mt-x64-1_74.lib"
                      "stage/lib/libboost_filesystem-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_74.lib"
                      "stage/lib/libboost_filesystem-vc142-mt-x64-1_74.lib" 
                      "stage/lib/libboost_iostreams-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_74.lib"
                      "stage/lib/libboost_iostreams-vc142-mt-x64-1_74.lib"
                      "stage/lib/libboost_program_options-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_74.lib"
                      "stage/lib/libboost_program_options-vc142-mt-x64-1_74.lib"
                      "stage/lib/libboost_regex-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_74.lib"
                      "stage/lib/libboost_regex-vc142-mt-x64-1_74.lib"
                      "stage/lib/libboost_system-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_74.lib"
                      "stage/lib/libboost_system-vc142-mt-x64-1_74.lib" 
                      "stage/lib/libboost_thread-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_74.lib"
                      "stage/lib/libboost_thread-vc142-mt-x64-1_74.lib"
                      
    DEPENDEES         launchBootstrap
    DEPENDERS         configure
    COMMENT           "Custom Configure Boost Step - build boost library"
    COMMAND           b2.exe --with-date_time --with-filesystem --with-regex --with-system --with-program_options --with-thread --with-iostreams --with-atomic
    USES_TERMINAL     1
)
```

What is wrong here? And where is a log for step processing?

Comment: It seems your b2 command is missing `link=static` option (see [here](https://boostorg.github.io/build/manual/develop/index.html#bbv2.tutorial.linkage) )

Comment: oh right, thank you. If it comes to the issue, right now I'm just setting the boost as target dependency for my another target and find package that is looking for BoostConfigure.cmake in generated stage folder sees it, but I find it weird solution and would like to generate stage folder with my libs and cmake configure settings at ***configure step*** as I try to do above

Comment: "cmake configures without any feedback and errors" - **Which** CMake invocation you are talking about? Is it the one, which configures your main project (NOT an external one)? Or is it the one which configures Boost? All steps of the external project are actually executed only when the main project is built.